# How can I add a Spinner to RecyclerView

Tags: android, spinner, android-recyclerview

When adding a navigation drawer to my app, I used a pattern that involves filling the first position of the `RecyclerView` with a header that contains an image and some `TextViews`.  This is all great, but now I want to add a `Spinner` in there too but am having trouble understanding how to set this up.

The problem is when I create dataAdapter, i get a "cannot resolve constructor".  I think it is due to not correctly supplying a `Context`?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```

At this point I am in the `ViewHolder` class within the `RecyclerAdapter` so "this" isn't an `Activity`.  I get that you can use parent.this or activity name.this but this doesn't seem right either (and doesn't work!).

How can I get round the "cannot resolve constructor" error?

Here is the whole `onBindViewHolder` within my `RecyclerAdapter`.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(navigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder.HolderID ==1) {                         
            holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
        }
        else{
            holder.imageProfile.setImageResource(profile);
            holder.textName.setText(name);
            holder.textEmail.setText(email);


            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("TEST");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            holder.siteSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.siteSpinner);

            holder.siteSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        }
    }
```

Alternatively, is this the right approach?  I wonder if creating a "header" in position one is a good way to go?  Could an alternative be to create a `LinearLayout` for my navigation drawer which has the `Spinner` and `RecyclerView` one after the other?

Comment: broken link, unable to access

Comment: Android has evolved significantly since this was posted.  I wouldn't look at a 5 year old post for tips personally. Broken link removed anyway :)

Comment: any answer that you can mark as the correct? even by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating the dataAdapter object in the method you use to initialize the RecyclerAdapter (ie: constructor) and pass to that method the context of the caller.

ex:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Vector<int> myItems, Context leContext) {
   ...
   dataAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(leContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure I follow the part about creating the dataAdapter in my calling method.  However passing in the activity object into my recycler adapter does seem to work.  I've read that this isn't the most efficient way to do things?